# How to use config variable in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am new in react-native and haven't use any starter kit.
my question is how can I use config variables. say for example i have api url which is diffrent for production and development. I don't want to go in each page change url every time.

That's why i want to use something like config variables.

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pretty simple question.. you can use `react-native-config`. Follow the steps:

`npm install react-native-config --save`

`react-native link react-native-config`

Create a new file .env in the root of your React Native app:

```
API_URL_LIVE=https://myapilive.com
API_URL_DEV=https://myapidev.com
```

Then access variables defined there from your app:
import Config from 'react-native-config'

```
Config.API_URL_LIVE  // 'https://myapilive.com'
```

Note: Don't forget to clean you build after changing the URLs. Use following command.

```
cd android 
gradlew clean build
```